# Failed to markdown parser function in php using regex

Tags: php, regex

Let's write a simple markdown parser function that will take in a single line of markdown and be translated into the appropriate HTML. To keep it simple, we'll support only one feature of markdown in atx syntax: headers.

Headers are designated by (1-6) hashes followed by a space, followed by text. The number of hashes determines the header level of the HTML output.

Examples

```
# Header will become <h1>Header</h1>
## Header will become <h2>Header</h2>
###### Header will become <h6>Header</h6>
```

My code :

```
function markdown_parser ($markdown) {
$regex = '/(?:(#+)(.+?)\n)|(?:(.+?)\n\s*=+\s*\n)/';
$headerText = $markdown."\n";
$headerText = preg_replace_callback(
    $regex,
    function($matches){
        if (!preg_match('/\s/',$matches[2])) {
            return "#".$matches[2];
        }
        if($matches[1] != ""){
           $h_num = strlen($matches[1]);
           return html_entity_decode("<h$h_num>".trim($matches[2])."</h$h_num>");
        }  
    },
    $headerText
);
return $headerText;
}
```

its not working as failed test case :

```
Failed asserting that two strings are identical.
Expected: Behind # The Scenes
Actual  : Behind <h1>The Scenes</h1>
```

Comment: How is that a failure? It has done exactly what you describe `# Header will become <h1>Header</h1>`

Comment: Failed asserting that two strings are identical.
Expected: ####### Snow White and the Seven Hashtags
Actual  : <h7>Snow White and the Seven Hashtags</h7>

Comment: @SelimReza, I am facing same issue. did you resolve this issue ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What i understood is you want to limit your markdown conversion to a range of 1-6 depth for your title.

Give a try to this code :

```
function markdown_parser ($markdown) {
    $regex = '/(?:(#+)(.+?)\n)|(?:(.+?)\n\s*=+\s*\n)/';
    $headerText = $markdown."\n";
    $headerText = preg_replace_callback(
        $regex,
        function($matches) use ($markdown){
            if (!preg_match('/\s/',$matches[2])) {
                return "#".$matches[2];
            }
            if($matches[1] != ""){
                $h_num = strlen($matches[1]);
                if (\in_array($h_num, \range(1, 6), true)) {
                    return html_entity_decode("<h$h_num>" . trim($matches[2]) . "</h$h_num>");
                }

                return $markdown;
            }
        },
        $headerText
    );
    return $headerText;
}
```

I only add a condition to check if your number of hashtag is in range of 1 until 6`if (\in_array($h_num, \range(1, 6), true)) {`

Comment: Same Error while submitting

Comment: sorry but it seems to work : `var_dump(markdown_parser('####### Header'));` return `string(14) "####### Header"` and `var_dump(markdown_parser('###### Header'))` return `string(15) "<h6>Header</h6>"`. What is the matter ?

Comment: getting error :: Failed asserting that two strings are identical.
`Expected: Behind # The Scenes`
`Actual  : Behind <h1>The Scenes</h1>`

Comment: It's the good behaviour, please read your post again : 
**# Header** will become **<h1>Header</h1>**